# PHP global count does not reset

Tags: php, global-variables

I am trying to write a function that counts the image while looping through the files for one case (out of many cases), I declared the variable `$imageCount` global within the function `copyInsertImage` so that after the image is successfully inserted into the database, I do an `$imageCount++`.

After processing all the images for the case, the code exits the loop, the function `processImages` will be recalled again. However, I did a `var_dump($imageCount)` to print out the image count each time it gets increased by one, and found out that it was never reset back to 0 by the `$imageCount = 0` when running the loop for a new case.

I am wondering if declaring `global $imageCount` has anything to do with it, because the code worked fine previously before grouping the same script into a function. If so, what is the solution?

Thanks!

```
function processImages($path,$patientID,$caseID)
{
    // $path = rootDirectory/patientID
    global $targetDirectory;
    $targetPath = $targetDirectory.$patientID;



    $caseSummaryFolder = $path."/".$caseID."/Summary";
    $srcDirPath=$path."/".$caseID."/Summary/slicesdir"; //AKA src
    $dstDirPath = $targetPath."/".$caseID;
    //copyCaseImages($caseSummaryFolder,$targetCasePath,$patientID,$caseID);

    global $status;
    // print("processImages case path:".$casePath."</br>");
    $files = glob($srcDirPath."/*.png");

    echo "\n------------NEW CASE------------\n"
    echo "PATIENT: $patientID \n";
    echo "CASE: $caseID \n";
    echo "--------------------------------\n"

    $imageCount = 0;
    for($i = 0; $i < count($files); $i++) {
        $file = $files[$i];
        $fileName = str_ireplace($srcDirPath."/", "", $file);
        // if image name doesn't not contain string 'GROT'
        if(strripos($fileName, "grot") === false)
        {
            if(doesImgExist($fileName)!==NULL) {
                if (compareFileMTime($srcDirPath,$fileName,doesImgExist($fileName))) {
                    echo "There's a newer version of $fileName \n";
                    copyInsertImage($srcDirPath,$dstDirPath,$fileName,$patientID,$caseID);
                }
                else {
                    $imageCount++;
                }
            }
            // copy image to analyzedCp and insert new image into DB
            else {
                copyInsertImage($srcDirPath,$dstDirPath,$fileName,$patientID,$caseID);

            }
        }   
        else {
            echo "grot*.png files are not included \n";
        }

    }
```

Comment: Instead of making it global, why don't you pass that variable into the function? Then have it return the updated $imageCount

Comment: Wouldn't you need to declare `$imageCount` as a global in  `processImages()`, too? Otherwise, you're just using a local variable.

Comment: So where is $imageCount defined as global?

Comment: @andrewsi Yep! 

Also I'm guessing you are getting the global $imagecount in copyInsertImage(). How about just setting $imagecount = 0 below the copyInsertImage call, or wouldn't that serve your cause?

Comment: @andrewsi Thanks! That solved it. But can someone elaborate on why is that? So when I'm assigning the global $imageCount within the copyInsertImage function, it is different from the $imageCount originally declared outside of the for-loop?

Comment: @alchuang - if you're using globals, you need to declare them as global in every function that uses them. Otherwise, you end up using a local variable with the same name. This is one of the reasons to try to avoid them if possible - it's easier to pass variables into functions when you need them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, it seems like you are redeclaring "global $imageCount" inside of your "copyInsertImage" function and this function is part of the for-loop.  If this is indeed what you have then a problem is that everything time your for-loop hits the "copyInsertImage" function it will take re-declare $imageCount, this re-declaration will make imageCount a new variable and clear whatever you have stored in it.  This could be the reason why you are seeing $imageCount = 0.

Answer (score 0):

@andrewsi Answered my question.

My question was solved by declaring the initial $imageCount as global too.

"if you're using globals, you need to declare them as global in every function that uses them. Otherwise, you end up using a local variable with the same name. This is one of the reasons to try to avoid them if possible - it's easier to pass variables into functions when you need them."

Thanks!